# On my stationary bike the left crank is loose only at the top

Tags: crankset

When I peddle, only at the top (pedal at it highest point) does the crank seems loose.  It feels like it skips a bit as I transition down.  It does not wiggle from left to right but only front to back.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the crankarm loose (i.e. is it moving relative to the other crankarm?) or is it bearing play (i.e. is the whole crankset moving relative to the frame in a direction it shouldn’t)?

Comment: Or is the pedal loose -- either loose where it screws in or with loose bearings?